# Localization issue on Xbox (UWP)

Tags: c#, uwp, localization

I have an error that occurs to a small percentage of users of my app, only on German Xbox. English users and PC users are fine.

My code looks like this:

```
Uri fileName = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Content/MyData.json");
StorageFile myFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(fileName);
IBuffer buf = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(myFile);
```

This is called from `App.xaml.cs` `OnLaunched` event on app start-up:

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
```

For the unlucky few the `ReadBufferAsync` statement results in `element not found` error:

```
System.Exception: Element nicht gefunden. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)
```

One user was good enough to reinstall the app, and the same error happens, so it seem to be persistent, it is not a timing issue on start-up or installation issue.

Json file is stored in these folders in my project for the two languages I support:

```
\Assets\Content\language-de\MyData.json
\Assets\Content\language-en\MyData.json
```

My suspicion is that the problem has to do with UWP localization as it does not seem to be happening to English language users which are a large majority of my users. I cannot replicate this myself. If I change the locale on my PC to `de-DE` or `de-CH` it works fine and it displays content in German.

I am only aware of the issue thanks to AppCenter reporting and one user taking the time to email me about it.

Any ideas what I could do to fix or work around this issue or at least how to get more info on what the issue is. I am not sure what the `element not found` error means in this context.

Comment: Can you check if  build action of MyData.json file  is `Content`?

Comment: Hi, yes, set as content and "copy always"

Comment: Well, please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/tailor-resources-lang-scale-contrast#language), and set `MyData.json` as `MyData.de.json` replace storing in the `language-de`  sub-folder

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that next. I am currently trying to have folders set up as de-DE and en-US. I have feeling resource manager may not like the language without the country. I have also changed the package manifest from "generate" to specifying languages explicitly:

  <Resources>
   <Resource Language="EN-US" />
   <Resource Language="DE-DE" />
  </Resources>

Comment: Well. please let me know which way works.

Comment: Neither workaround worked. I managed to replicate the issue by changing my Xbox to Swiss German (`de-CH`) so I can try a few more things without bugging my user. I managed to capture the path Xbox is looking for: `S:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\[DEV_ID].[APP_ID]_[VERSION].70_neutral_split.language-de_bs4e86aaf1n92\\Assets\\Content`. Maybe I need to add `und` language? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/how-rms-matches-lang-tags#undetermined-language-und

Comment: Or create a file for each German speaking region (de-AT, de-CH, de-LI...)

Comment: Yep, that's a workaround for this thread, you could report this problem with windows feedback hub, and post above comment as an answer then mark yourself to convenient people who visit this thread later.

Comment: I have added Swiss German (de-CH) language to the app and it still doesn't work! So I am fresh out of ideas. I can see that the app is looking for the right file `myData.language-de-CH.json`, but it is not finding the file. It's either that the file was not copied or it's looking in the wrong place!

Comment: Just had an idea! I will not use Microsoft localization resource manager. Instead I will detect the language myself and load the right file. That should work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried a few different things, but it was not working. Seems there is an issue with developer content localization on Xbox. String localization works OK.

As a workaround I ended up implementing my own logic to select the correct file instead of relying on Microsoft resource manager:

```
Uri fileName = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Content/MyData.english.json");

string topUserLanguage = GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0];

//override default file if german language is detected                
if(topUserLanguage.StartsWith("de"))
{
    fileName = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Content/MyData.german.json");
}
```